# Modifying application startup order via wsadmin

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

Is it possible to modify the value of an application's startup-order using either `AdminApp.install(...)` or any other wsadmin command?

This property is under Enterprise Applications > *application name* > Startup behavior > Startup order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, it can be done like this:

```
AdminConfig.modify(
  AdminConfig.showAttribute(
    AdminConfig.getid("/Deployment:applicationname/"),
    "deployedObject"),
  [['startingWeight','99']])
```

In typical, straight-forward wsadmin style. >.<